# CTL* query evaluation order

Tags: logic, model-checking, computation-tree-logic, temporal-logic

I'm currently trying to evaluate a CTL* expression and am not sure how to stepwisely evaluate the queries. 
For example I have **EFG p**. This means something like 'there is a path where eventually there exists a state s where from there on, globally p holds true'.

Globally means that for all successors of a state on all paths starting at this state a certain property holds true.

Applied to the example above, this would mean when evaluating EFGp on a model with init-state s0, that there exists a path from s0 to a state s' where from there on all succeeding paths have the property p.
But wouldn't this imply that this is equivalent to **EFAG p**?

Is it in general possible to evaluate such queries stepwise (operator by operator) or do I have to consider all operators at once?

best regards

Comment: In class you were taught the semantics of CTL* expressions. The semantics tell you the meaning of every possible expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretation of the $G$ modality is incorrect; it does not inherently talk about all paths. In particular, the example you give specifies that there is a path such that from some point on, all states *on that path* satisfy $p$.

As you suspect, for CTL* it is in general not possible to use a simple bottom-up evaluation, as you would for CTL, the reason being the LTL-like nested temporal operators.

Comment: ok so for the previous example EFGp the subterm FGp is evaluated with respect to a single path (and E obviously looks for one path that satisfies this property). 
in the other example EFAGp, EF looks for some state s and for this state s, all possible successor states s' (on all paths starting at s) assert property p.
Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: @hubsi Yes, that is correct.